# Is $\forall n\exists m:\, m^2=n,\text{ where }m,n ∈ \mathbb N$ true or false?

Tags: logic, proof-verification

$\forall n\exists m:\, m^2=n,\text{ where }m,n ∈ \mathbb N$. Prove whether this expression is true or false.

My attempt:
False, take $n=3,$ then there is no such integer $m$, such that $m^2=3$. Thus, we can say not all $n$, there exist $m$, such that $m^2=n$.

Is this correct?

Comment: You are correct.  The statement is essentially that all natural numbers are perfect squares (which, as you point out, is false).

Comment: Yes, you're right. Also, the given counterexample is enough to prove that the statement is false. Therefore, you're done.

Comment: You have exhibited a proof that the statement is false by giving a counterexample. **Edit:** Whoops, this is identical to the previous comment by @Andre. So +1 to him.

Comment: It depends on what you are being asked to prove.  Can you prove that there is no $n$ such that $n^2 = 3$?  If you are only learning about quantifiers, then your proof is sufficient, but if you are supposed to be learning something like peano arithmetic, then it probably is not.

Answer (score 1):

That's correct, providing one counterexample  is sufficient to prove that the statement in question is false. You may also note that the statement   basically states that all natural numbers are perfect squares, which is of course false.

Depending on the circumstances, you might still need to elaborate on your proof i.e. give a "full" prove of the fact that $3$ is not a perfect square.

Comment: @gebruiker Thanks for the improvement.